# Pip Install Troubles

Tags: python

Currently trying to get python up and working on my work laptop which has proven to be a huge pain in the you know what.

It seems like the PATHing is all screwed up even with pip installing packages. For example, I tried to install seaborn today via pip install seaborn which ran successfully but when I try to import it on Visual Studio it has the yellow squiggly underneath it. I try to reinstall it but it says it has already been satisfied.

Is there anyway to manually re-route all of my python libraries to where I actually know whats going on? I have the PATH set to the correct library in environment variables but it still does not read that I have seaborn installed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: check out these docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments. Figure out where the python executable you're using to install things is with e.g. `which python` or `which python3`. Make sure you can import the libararies you're installing when you start python using that exact executable. Then point vscode to that python executable by following the linked instructions. Best in general to use a environments, e.g. with `venv` or `conda`. This will be hard, but you'll get the hang of it :)

Comment: From your question, I understand that you did something with pip and VS and it didn't work. That's far from enough info in your description, so please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can create python virtual environment and install your libraries on it.

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-python-virtual-environments-on-ubuntu-18-04/

It creates a isolated area for your specific project.

Comment: I think it is an issue with seaborn itself. I have installed it completely and even went to the root folder where all the packages are. I got the yellow squiggly away and thought I was good until I tried to run it and it said "no module named 'seaborn'. I am so lost and confused. Every other package works fine.

Comment: No matter what I do or what environment I create, seaborn refuses to be used on my computer.  Every other package works just fine besides seaborn.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have different python installations on your system.
If that's the case it might also be the case that the python you are using in visual studio isn't the python that is packages are being installed for via a straight forward `pip` command.

You could try to instead of `pip install ...` call `python -m pip install ...`. That ensures that you are using the pip of the python installation

Comment: I have everything working completely fine besides seaborn. I have tried virtual environments, opening the folder with seaborn directly in it in visual studio, everything. I don't understand why seaborn refuses to be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to install all dependencies `(seaborn, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, etc)` in a `virtual environment`, that means that you can have its own independent set of installed Python packages in its environment.

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) the python documentation on how to work with virtual environments on different OS.

Also, check which python versions you have installed on your machine. If you have both `python2` and `python3`, use `pip3` and `python3` on terminal whenever you want to install or run something.

Comment: I have installed everything into a virtual environment but seaborn still refuses to be used. Every package works completely fine besides seaborn.